# Not able to get list of ManytoMany field using filter

Tags: python, django, orm

views

```
create = Create.objects.filter(campaign_id=campaign_id).values()
print (create)
saved = create.produces.filter(active=True).values()
print(saved)
```

models

```
class Create(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE,blank=True)
campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
produces = models.ManyToManyField(Saved,blank=True)



class Saved(models.Model): 
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE,blank=True)
unique_key = models.CharField(max_length=2000,default='')
text = models.CharField(max_length=2000,default='')
active = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
```

How to get all saved with active=True

It is giving error of
saved = create.produces.filter(active=True).values()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'produces'

in the output of print(create) their is no produce field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here create is a queryset , it's like a list
When you have a list of numbers say :

```
list = [1,2,3]
```

you cant run number methods on that list object
So what you should do is :

```
all_objs = {}
for obj in create:
    objs = obj.produces.filter(active=True).values()
    all_objs.update(objs)
```

print(all_objs)